# Unable to save images by dragging and dropping them from browser to Nautilus or desktop

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, browser

In Chrome on Windows I usually save images by dragging them from the browser to the folder I want to save them to. I prefer this method compared to navigating through the file browser as it is much faster.

When I do the same in Ubuntu it saves a link to the image instead of the actual image. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Same behavior with firefox in 11.10. Used to save pictures in 10.04. No idea if there's a fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dragging the image onto the desktop/nautilus, pressing Ctrl (and dragging a bit more) before dropping saves a copy.

Comment: Not when the image links to another page. Any suggestions in that case?